# Python: Converting List of Tuples to JSON value key pairs

Tags: python, json

I've been trying to figure out the best way to handle the conversion from list to well-formatted JSON.

I have the list called 'headers' that can include x number of tuples, which are always formatted in such a way that `headers[x][0]` is a **key**, and `headers[x][1]` is a **value**.

[image]

Essentially, I need something that converts the list of tuples into JSON of key-value pairs, where output looks something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `json` module:

```
headers = [('Subject', 'Homebrew & Mold'), ('Line', '13')]

import json
result = json.dumps(dict(headers))

print(result)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
{"Subject": "Homebrew & Mold", "Line": "13"}
```

One-liner using list-comprehension:

```
print([{x[0]: x[1]} for x in headers])
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[{'Subject': 'Homebrew & Mold'}, {'Line': '13'}]
```

Comment: Ah dear, that couldn't get any easier.... I was missing the 'dict' in my json.dumps... Thank you!

Comment: @jjj hah, happens all the time, glad it helped! ^^

Answer (score 1):

I would be something like:

```
import json

headers = [('Subject', 'Homebrew & Mold'), ('Line', '13')]
results = []
for item in headers:
    results.append(dict([item]))
jsonified = json.dumps(results)
```

Output:

```
[{"Subject": "Homebrew & Mold"}, {"Line": "13"}]
```

It can be further simplified, a little. But, you'll get an idea.